# Exclusive Layouts for certain api level - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-api-levels

I have a Layout that I would like to use only for tablets. I know that if create a folder "layout-v(api level)" that layout will be used only for that specific api. the thing is, for tablets, either you have api 11, 12, or 13. Is there a way I can create a folder that includes all of these instead of creating layout-v11, layout-v12, layout-v13 ?

Hope my question is not confusing, i just dont know how to put my question any other way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185507/layout-for-tablets-in-android

Comment: Yes I did @0gravity , the problem remains the same, I will have duplicate layouts. I just want a folder where can treat all kinds of tablets, dont want to distinguish their size, api level or density.

Comment: "...dont want to distinguish their size, api level or density" Then how? I don't know what else would be different between a phone an a tablet bessides the resolution.  I guess you can ask the user if he is using a tablet, and then have an if statement that would use the xml file that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that you can have a 4" android device with API lvl 14. So using API version to distinct tablets and phones is not a good way.

Prefer the distinction with screen resolution. A good post about it is on the Android developers blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html

Comment: Good point. Didn't even catch that he was using API level to distinguish tablets.

Answer (score 13):

If you use `layout-v11` it will be used for all versions >= 11 unless a higher version is specified (e.g. `layout_v14`). So you should only need to make the one folder, `layout-v11`.

Comment: Thanks, and taking all the answers in consideration, I will use screen size to distinguish. Thanks