# Resize text on tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

With the use of `weight` my layouts are really perfect on every screen size and density. Every view is perfectly scaled.
Unfortunately there is still a big problem with characters size: no matter if I define text size with sp or dp, it still resizes based on density and not on size of the screen, so on tablets text is microtiny!!

What's the best solution for this problem?

- Shall I define different layouts for tablets? And in that case, how can I do it?
- Is there a way to auto-size the text, in xml or by code (I don't care much which one, if it works)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185507/layout-for-tablets-in-android. So yes you have to define a different layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create separate styles for different screen size qualifiers `small`, `normal`, `large`, `xlarge`, and a bunch of new `sw<N>dp`, `h<N>dp`, `w<N>dp`

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the second `h<N>dp` be `w<N>dp`?

Comment: This probably is the best answer but - to say it all - makes concrete my worst nightmares :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

use different layouts for different screen size

**Solution 2**

Use customView and change the text size dynamically. For example

```
    public class CustomView extends TextView{
         ....................

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                 calculate the view size and change the text size

        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**

To measure the size you can use following

```
        float size = getHeight() * .8; // getheight will return view's height
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```

Comment: Thank you, god idea, but the problem remains: how to calculate text size to match view size?

Comment: wait .. trying to give a basic idea .. (not exact, you may figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of dimens.xml which you need to create in your values folder and create values folder as values-large values-small values-xlarge etc.....