# Android layout correct alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am working on a project and I have run into some problems. I haven't worked with the layouts very much so I don't know if this is possible or not.

In the picture I have added the project mock-up. For the lower screen resolution it looks fine, but when I put the app on 5 inch device, this orange area is too high and I wanted to know if it is possible somehow to get that area centered.

[image]

The orange area is a LinearLayout and everything is wrapped inside LinearLayout. Hope you understand what I mean I what I am asking.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff0000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:background="#175797"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Subject" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFA500"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is code for the mock-up. For the project it's pretty much the same

Comment: post your layout xml file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try @g00dy answer or else

You have to create separate layout for phablet (i.e. 5 inch devices)

[Here in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944886/1758960) they had explain how we can put our tablets layouts...

On android developer site they have had explain **how android manage layouts for different screen sizes** [check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

I tried putting Linear layout inside a relative layout and defining its gravity. I checked it on various resolution.Give it a try

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff0000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:background="#175797"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Subject" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#00FFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFA500"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try `android:layout_gravity="center"` that should do the trick :)
Also in addition, you can add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and take a look at [this thread](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

for giving the compatibility of xml for all android devices and tablets, please use the Relative Layout as a parent view and set the component according to your requirement.
please follow this link for more reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html