# Create custom layout for tablet and phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-custom-view

I need to create a custom layout that will contain two rows on tablet that will show featured and regular items(no scrolling needed), and listview on a phone that shows only the featured items. Is it possible to create a layout like this, is there some library that someone can share with me that will help me create this kind of layout?

Here is how it should look on the tablet:

[image]

And here is how it should look on the phone:

[image]

Comment: this might be flagged as duplicate, google gives tons of resources - one possible solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185507/layout-for-tablets-in-android

Comment: yes its possible use two layouts one for tablet and other for phone

**layout-sw720dp** for 10 inches tablet
**layout-sw600dp** for 7 inches tablet
*layout* for other sizes

P.S.:-Add these folders in res and add xml with same names

Comment: Go through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Question hardly shows any research. As @mihail points out, there are tons of easy to find resources, including [Android Developers' website](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 4):

Create layouts in following folders

**res/layout-w1280dp** - for 10 inch devices

**res/layout-w820dp** - for 7 inch devices

**res/layout** - for everything else

Do not use:

**res/layout-large** may be not correctly detected. Rely on dp size shown above

Comment: Hi robotoaster. I have one question regarding to this answer. Does It Support all tablet layout screen? Today in Market there is one more device dell venue 8 This device have 8inch screen Is this layout you mention will support it for all tablet?

Comment: try to establish what is width dp of that device and add extra res/layout for it. Some devices are more troublesome e.g. LG Pad, has 8 inches but system recognises it as 7in

Answer (score 1):

First detect the device is a phone or a tablet. You can do it by calculating the device screen size.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
double x = Math.pow(metrics.widthPixels/metrics.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(metrics.heightPixels/metrics.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("debugging","Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

And also use different layouts in `res` folder. In your code decide whether to initiate a `ListView` or a `LinearLayout`.