# Fit layout only for Nexus 10 device

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-10

I have a xml layout file where i am giving margin-top for a text value.

For all the device it is `android:layout_marginTop="25dp"`.
But its not coming proporly in **Nexus 10** device.I want to increase the margin only for Nexus 10 device.
How can i achieve this.Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: you can create a separate directory for the resolution matching nexus 10's and place the layout in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the my solution, it's definitely fix your issue.

You have to create different **dimens files** inside the values folder for different screens. Like,

values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi

values-xxhdpi           5.5"  1080x1920 xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi           5.5" 1440x2560 xxxhdpi

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi

[image]

For more information you may visit here

> [Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)
>
> [http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

You can make use of Android Studio plugin called [Dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify) to auto generate dimension values for other pixel buckets based on custom scale factors. Its still in beta, be sure to notify any issues/suggestions you come across to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you should create separate asset folders for your requirement and then place the layout file in it:

Just for giving you the idea this is the normal practice.

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Also take a look at [Official Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) for more help.

And this question will also give you the idea :
[Layout for tablets in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185507/layout-for-tablets-in-android)